# VM428:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror') at <anonymous>:7:17

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code is running nicely but I don't understand where I get this error:

```
VM428:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')
    at <anonymous>:7:17
```

Comment: post the code related `CodeMirror`

Comment: I really don't know where is it sir, where can I find it?

Answer (score 25):

Remove `blackbox` extension and `react development tool` extension from chrome

Comment: what's the problem with the `blackbox` and `rdt` ??

Comment: Removing blackbox helped me. I still have react developer tools.

Comment: Same here just removing blackbox got rid of the problem

Answer (score 12):

Just Remove **blackbox** extension from your chrome and its done