# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime-error

**VM32:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')
at :7:17**

I getting this error without writing any wrong JS.
[Error Image Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6w2ws.png)

[image: This is list of my extension that I have installed]

Comment: Then solve this error, young man

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VM428:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror') at <anonymous>:7:17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74485409/vm4287-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-codemirror)

Comment: I removed the black box extension and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Just Remove Blackbox extension extension from chrome.

Comment: I haven't Installed any BlackBox extension

Comment: It's the top third extension in image.